# importing maven depedency as pom

Tags: java, maven

I need to import a dependency in my project; The problem is that that dependency is specified by a pom in this way:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>it.xxxx.yyyyy.be.esb</groupId>
    <artifactId>CR_XXXXX_BE_PRODO_YYYYYY_V1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>pom</type>
 </dependency>
```

When I add this dependency in my project it compile well, and in my local repository (.m2) I find the folder at the path it.xxxx.yyyyy.be.esb;

But not find any jar inside the folder, so How I can use that dependency?
That dependency should be a client to make soap call to a server!

In other project the dependency was:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>it.xxxx.yyyyy.be.esb</groupId>
    <artifactId>CR_XXXXX_BE_PRODO_YYYYYY_V1</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>jar</type>
 </dependency>
```

And when I compile, the jar file is downloaded and i'm able to find it in my local repository (.m2), also I can decompile and see all class inside the package, and I can import in my class;

So my question is, is there a way to use the first dependency (the one with pom as type: pom)?

thanks

Comment: When you add a dependency of type pom, all you get are the transitive dependencies listed in that pom.  If you want the jar, you have to use `type` named jar (or better yet, don't list the type at all).  The only place I use `type` is to include poms in the dependency management section.

Comment: if I change to <type>jar</type> or delete it at all, when compile it complains that " Could not resolve dependencies for project...."

Answer (score -1):

In `dependencyManagement` you can import a "bill of materials" (BOM) that is provided in `pom` format. Here all the supplied components, their requirements and their versions are included so that you know that you are using all the versions that the BOM provider used.

For example, Spring boot (I know you can do it as a parent pom):

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
.
.
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In their BOM, all the versions of the Spring Boot dependencies, including the versions of their plugins, are defined in one place.

Another good example is junit:

```
<!-- use dependency management to import pom -->
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-bom</artifactId>
            <version>5.9.2</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
.
.
<dependencies>
    <!-- Version is defined in the parent pom -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: maybe you could supply a couple of sentences stating HOW this answers the question. Read [answer] for tips

Comment: If I try to implement as you described i get error on compilation: [ERROR]   The project it.yyyyyy.xxxxxx.fe:CR_xxxxxx_FE_aaaaa_bbbbbbbb:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT (C:\Users\f.rossi\git\xxxxxx_FE_PTL_aaaaa\CR_xxxxxx_FE_aaaaa_bbbbbbbb\pom.xml) has 1 error
[ERROR]     'dependencies.dependency.version' for it.yyyyyy.tttttt.be.esb:CR_tttttt_BE_PRODO_dddddd_V1:jar is missing. @ line 116, column 15

Comment: Who ever created the BOM has done it wrong if the versions of the components it defines aren't included. That is the whole idea of using a BOM for dependency management. Search for "dependencyManagement bom", there are many sites that describe what it is and how it works.